# Check Google site if page name already exists when uploading folders

Tags: google-apps-script

I am uploading folders to a created google site using appscript, but sometimes an error occures during which the code is uploading the filenames to the site as a parentpage and does not finish uploading all hte file names. So, when I restart the code it will throw an error saying that a page with that name already exists. Is there a way to do an if statement around the create page portion of code so that it checks to see if the name already exists. the code is provided below,

```
while (folders.hasNext()) {

var folder = folders.next();
if (folder.getName() == "Work_Orders(Evadale)3"){
  Logger.log("I made it into the uploads folder");

  var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
  while(subFolders.hasNext()){

    var subFolder = subFolders.next();
    var files = subFolder.getFilesByType('text/html');
    var stringChange = subFolder.getName();
    var parentname = stringChange.replace(" ","-");

    for (var c = 0; c<5; c++){
      parentname = parentname.replace(" ","-");
      parentname = parentname.replace("#","_");
      parentname = parentname.replace("(","-");
      parentname = parentname.replace(")","-");
      parentname = parentname.replace("&","and");
    }
    Logger.log(parentname);
    Logger.log("About to enter the if statement");


    var pageParent = site.createWebPage(parentname, parentname, "");
    var counter = 0;

    while (files.hasNext()){

      Logger.log(maxFiles);
      var file = files.next();
      var html = file.getBlob();
      var datas = html.getAs('text/plain');
      var infoString = datas.getDataAsString(); //this has a quota, see if this can be done some other way?
      var name = file.getName();
      Logger.log(name);
      name = name.replace(".html","");

      cache.put("parent"+maxFiles,parentname);
      cache.put("child"+maxFiles, name);
      cache.put("infoString"+maxFiles, infoString);
      maxFiles++;
    }

    Logger.log("Counter"+counter);
    Logger.log("maxFiles"+maxFiles);
    Logger.log("Just exited the if statement");
    cache.put("counter", counter);

  } 
}
cache.put("maxFiles", maxFiles);
cache.put("begin", begin);
cache.put("end",end);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the `getAllDescendants()` method?

[Google Documentation - getAllDescendants()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site#getAllDescendants())

That would get you an array of descendant page names.  Then you could use the JavaScript `indexOf()` method of the array name to check if the page name exists in the array.

[JavaScript indexOf() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: or use a try / catch structure to trap the error and skip the already existing pages ? but +1 for clarity and simplicity.